# Where to start reading the scala source code?

Tags: scala

I know there's a lot question about 'How/Where to start reading the xxx code'.
But it's a important question.
I am a new scala user and I really like this language, I want to understand deeper about how scala works.
So I decide to read the source code,but I don't know how to start.

I want to establish a systematic understanding about scala,so can someone give me some advice about where to start read scala source code or introduce some helpful books.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question will quite likely be closed as too broad or off-topic or whatever, but I don't mind answering it.

Most common answers to this question usually include:

- Programming in Scala by Odersky & Co. ([link](https://www.amazon.de/Programming-Scala-3rd-Martin-Odersky/dp/0981531687/ref=asc_df_0981531687/?tag=googshopde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310654880846&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14924382228428120053&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061132&hvtargid=pla-432160343176&psc=1&th=1&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=65855312310&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=310654880846&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14924382228428120053&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061132&hvtargid=pla-432160343176))
- Coursera
  courses, especially Functional Programming Principles in Scala
  ([link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1))

I used these two in parallel with implementing what I learned, both at work (we were just starting with Scala) and in hobby projects.

If you're talking about specific GitHub projects to read code, there are plenty of great libraries, but to be honest they might be a bit advanced for beginners. Pretty much all of the good ones are using advanced FP concepts and libraries such as [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) or [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), and it might be a bit early for that right now.

So my answer, especially since you asked about fundamentals of the language, is to focus on material such as the aforementioned book and the Coursera course, and implement what you learn in practice through a hobby project.

You might also find some really nice blog posts all around the place, but they are usually targeting a specific topic, so you can refer to those from time to time as you encounter certain concepts (e.g. typeclasses).

Comment: As for books there is "the read book", functional programming in scala and I also liked modern web development in scala on leanpub.

Comment: I completely agree with @Saskia - the red book is great! But it's about more advanced FP concepts, not really the fundamentals of the language.

Comment: Just noting that since this question was answered the [fourth edition](https://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala_4ed) of Odersky & Co. was released and I don't know if this is new but the first edition is [available free online](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/)! There's also a list of recommended books in the [Scala docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/books.html).